# Saving Sprite Position

Tags: java, libgdx, position, sprite

I have a sprite that when reaches a certain position it gets removed:

```
 if(sprite.getY()>=700){
      enemyIterator.remove();
      Pools.free(sprite);
}
```

I wan't to save the last position of the sprite before it gets removed,I tried `sprite.getX()` and `sprite.getY()` but those are only usable while the sprite is in the game.

Comment: Are you keeping references to sprites after their removal? When do you need to use these positions? Is it right after the removal or sometime later?

Comment: Can't you just save it right before your `enemyIterator.remove();` line?

Comment: @plastique I'm gonna use their position after they are removed.

Comment: @Tenofur04 I can use their position before they get removed, but when the sprite is removed their coordinates is also removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on provided additional information.
Sprite methods `getX()` and `getY()` returns float values. So you can assign values returned by these methods to variables of type `float` for later use.

```
float lastX, lastY;

if(sprite.getY()>=700){
  lastX = sprite.getX();
  lastY = sprite.getY();
  enemyIterator.remove();
  Pools.free(sprite);
}

System.out.println("Removed sprite coordinates where: " + lastX + ", " + lastY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't get the last position where the sprite is , but you can save the last position what you draw in this frame , you always need to set a position when you draw every frame and if something happen , catch the last position , for example .

```
private Rectangle bordes;

public Ball(float x, float y,int isMoved) {
    ..........
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bola.png"));
        bordes = new Rectangle(x, y, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
    ..........
    }

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) { 
    //where i draw my last texture or sprite  was bordes.x bordes.y in this frame
        batch.draw(texture, bordes.x, bordes.y, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
    }

public vois getLastPosition(){

lastX = bordes.x;
lastY = bordes.y;

}
```